# Read arraylist from Realtime Database and send it to Receycler adapter of type Object

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I have an ArrayList of type object. This arraylist contains String elements, stored in Realtime Database.
I want to read it and send it to the Receycler adapter, but it prints null, what is the solution, please help me.

```
public class Child {
private String childName,parentEmail,parentId,childId,childToken;
private int hour,minute,seconds;
private ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

public Child() {
}

public Child(String childName, String parentEmail, String parentId, String childId,String childToken,
             int hour,int minute,int seconds,ArrayList<String> images) {
    this.childName = childName;
    this.parentEmail = parentEmail;
    this.parentId = parentId;
    this.childId = childId;
    this.childToken = childToken;
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.seconds = seconds;
    this.images = images;
}
```

*Here this code works to take pictures from realtime and send them to the adapter to display the pictures*

```
private ActivityChildPressedFromHomeBinding binding;
private Intent intent;
private String childIdFromHome,parenId;
private DatabaseReference mDbRef,reference1;
private SessionManager manager;
private ArrayList<Child> images;
private showImage imageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityChildPressedFromHomeBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    manager = new SessionManager(this);
    HashMap<String,String> parentDetails = manager.getParentsDetailFromSession();
    parenId = parentDetails.get(SessionManager.ParentId);
    intent = getIntent();
    childIdFromHome = intent.getStringExtra("childFromHome");

    binding.activityChildPressedRec.setHasFixedSize(true);
    binding.activityChildPressedRec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    images = new ArrayList<>();
    imageAdapter = new showImage(images,child_pressedFromHome.this);
    binding.activityChildPressedRec.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    mDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Parents").child(parenId)
            .child("Children").child(childIdFromHome);
    mDbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
               Child child = dataSnapshot.getValue(Child.class);
               images.add(child);
               System.out.println("xxxxxx " + images);
            }
            System.out.println("xxxxxxS " + images);
            imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code as text and **not** as an image.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: After the for loop, it does not read the array from the Realtime database, it does not print anything for me

Comment: my error : Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.bitirme_projesi.Data.Child

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I solved the problem, thanks for your interest..